# Save a pipeline Logistic Regression model

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, pipeline

```
lrmodel=logreg_pipeline.fit(X_train_resh,y_train_resh)
```

```
lrmodel.write().overwrite().save("E:/strokestuff/strokelrpred")
```

```
lrmodel.save("E:/strokestuff/strokelrpred")
```

lrmodel is a pipeline, I want to save it, My aim is to save this model then load it to deploy it in Flutter. I have tried every solution I got, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `joblib` to save your model in `.joblib` file:

```
import joblib

pipe_clf_params = {}
filename = 'E:/strokestuff/strokelrpred/strokelrpred.joblib'

pipe_clf_params['pipeline'] = lrmodel
joblib.dump(pipe_clf_params, filename)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to accept it, I have done that now.
When I am loading the saved model to convert it to tflite model it says, the saved model file does not exist

Comment: Load that file like this : `pipeline = joblib.load(filename)`. Please use the same `filename` as a mentioned in my answer.

Comment: ```import tensorflow as tf
import os
 
# Convert the model
#mypath ='E:/strokestuff/strokelr/strokelr.pb'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(filename) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
 
# Save the model.
with open('stroke_lr.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)```
I have to load and convert it to tflite, but that doesn't happen.
I get an OS error -OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: E:/strokestuff/strokelr/strokelrpred.pb\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}